# Node js Javascript process

Tags: node.js

I have this high-CPU consuming Node js Javascript process which keeps launching up when I start my PC and eats up a lot of CPU and memory that I have to manually shut down every time. This feels like a virus almost. How can I shut this down for good or uninstall it? Thanks!

[image]

P.S. My apologies if this is the wrong board. If so let me know where this would belong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi did you see the attached image?  There is a process Node-js that's being launched on my PC upon start which I have to kill every time and I cannot see where it came from and I need to remove it from my PC.